# Automate GWT build in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, gwt, automated-tests, build-automation

Is there a way to automate a GWT build using the eclipse project?

The aim is to have an automated build:
  * Check out from Version Control System
  * Building the GWT Project
  * Deploy the GWT Project
  * Run Tests

I have read about ant, but is there a way to reuse the Eclipse project files for the GWT project?

Comment: How about configuring Eclipse from your build script rather than trying to "reuse your Eclipse configuration" from within some automated build? Eclipse has built-in support for Maven for instance, and there are plugins for Gradle, Ivy, etc. (though the Google Plugin for Eclipse only integrates with Maven)